# Jasper Report - Text being truncated when column does not have enough size

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am doing a Jasper Report to generate excel via JasperSoft Studio 6.6.0.

I am encounter the issue where the text is not display in full when the column has not enough space. The text is being truncated.

The text should be: **AAAAA,BBBBB,CCCCC,DDDDD,EEEEE,FFFFF,GGGGG,HHHHH**

[image]

Please guide on this.

Comment: What do you mean by column? Excel one, as I presume. I have known excel columns to contain whole books of data, the data you have presented is very small! Excel won't have any problem with this, problem lies somewhere else... please check jasper report class specs

Comment: Hi Ketan,
Yes. I knew that the excel can do that. I assume this is the problem with the jasper report jrxml there.